# Draw rectangles on canvas by reading JSON

Tags: javascript, json, canvas

I'm trying to draw rectangles on a HTML5 canvas. I managed to draw on the canvas but I need to do it dynamically.

`x`, `y`: coordinates of the position of the rectangle in the canvas-element.
`w`: width of the rectangle.
`h`: height of the rectangle.
`f`: If `true`, the rectangle filled without a border. If `false` the rectangle has a border but no filling.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("c");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var json = [{
    "x": "50",
    "y": "50",
    "w": "100",
    "h": "50",
    "f": "true"
  },
  {
    "x": "50",
    "y": "150",
    "w": "100",
    "h": "50",
    "f": "false"
  }
];

context.beginPath();
for (var i in json) {
  context.lineTo(json[i].x, json[i].y, json[i].w, json[i].h, json[i].f)
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Comment: We need more context here, please. Can you edit the question to include a description of what you're trying to achieve, and also why your current code doesn't meet your needs.

Comment: That being said, [`lineTo()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/lineTo) expects only X and Y coordinates. What are you expecting `w`, `h` and `f` to do?

Comment: Thanks for editing, I added an answer for you below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're attempting to draw rectangles on your canvas, it would make far more sense to use the `strokeRect()` and `fillRect()` methods.

Note that your `f` property will determine which one of these methods are invoked. I would also suggest you convert the `f` property value to be a boolean, instead of a string.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("c");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var json = [{x: "50", y: "50", w: "100", h: "50", f: "true" }, { x: "50", y: "150", w: "100", h: "50", f: "false" }];

context.canvas.width = 200;
context.canvas.height = 250;

json.forEach(shape => {
  context[shape.f === 'true' ? 'fillRect' : 'strokeRect'](shape.x, shape.y, shape.w, shape.h);
});
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have an exam tomorrow and just couldnt figure this exercise out. How can I change the colours of the rectangle to red and the stroke width to 2px?

Also the last part of the exercise  was to create a handlebar-Template. The template is supposed to put out the x-y-postions of any number of rectangles that are saved to the variable "rects". I suppose rects is meant to include all of the data in the json file.

I hope I could explain it in a way its understandable.

Comment: You can use [`fillStyle` and `strokeStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Applying_styles_and_colors) to set the colour of the fill or the border. I'd suggest starting a new question about the handlebars template as have no experience there.